# yarn link and production build

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

We are using yarn link to refer to internal packages to speedup the dev workflow which has been helping great since we don't have to publish for each change.

However, when we want to create a production build using `yarn install --prod`, it is not copying the latest linked version but version which is available in npmjs.org (published version).

Have you come across this issue? Is there a way to instruct yarn to use local versions during install instead of picking latest published versions?

Comment: have you found any solution to this ? really interested in, had the same question